# T-SQL for combining 2 columns' values into one with "replicate"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a table with values like this:

```
Sets | Reps
-----+------
2    | 10
3    | 15
3    | 12
4    | 8
```

I need to combine those two values into one in my SELECT statement, so I could get

```
SELECT ... AS Reps FROM Table

Reps
------------
10,10
15,15,15
12,12,12
8,8,8,8
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Testing script:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE ([Sets] INT, [Reps] INT);

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 10);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 15);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 12);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 8);

SELECT [Sets], [Reps] FROM @Test;

// Here is an answer by tpdi:
SELECT CAST([Reps] AS VARCHAR) +
       REPLICATE(',' + CAST([Reps] AS VARCHAR), [Sets] - 1)
       AS [Reps] FROM @Test;
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are you doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
select substring(replicate(','+cast(Reps as varchar),Sets),2,8000) as Reps
from Table
```

Answer (score 2):

select cast(reps as varchar) + replicate( ',' + cast(reps as varchar), sets - 1)
from table

Answer (score 0):

select  SUBSTRING(REPLICATE(CAST([Reps] as varchar)+',' , [Sets]),
         0,
              LEN(REPLICATE(CAST([Reps] as varchar)+',' , [Sets]))
                  ) as [Reps]
from @Test

Comment: String indexes are one based, not zero based. The substring call doesn't remove anything as you are using the full length of the string.